# Определение переопределённой шаблонной функции

Tags: c++

Есть следующая иерархия классов, в которой хочу дать определение функции `bar`:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    using ARet = T;

    virtual ~A() = default;

    ARet foo();
    virtual ARet bar() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
T A<T>::foo() { // OK, return type matches that in the declaration (T = ARet)
    return 42;
}

template<typename T>
struct B : A<T> {
    using BaseType = A<T>;
    using BRet = typename BaseType::ARet;

    BRet bar() override;
};

template<typename T>
T B<T>::bar() { // Error, return type differs from that in the declaration ( but T = BRet = ARet ??? )
    return 42;
}
```

Однако, если более явно указать возвращаемый тип, то всё работает:

```
template<typename T>
typename B<T>::BRet B<T>::bar() { // OK
    return 42;
}
```

Но реальные типы гораздо длиннее, и не хочется подобным образом везде писать. Есть ли какие-нибудь альтернативы, и почему вообще так происходит?

Comment: Visual C++ спокойно компилирует.

Comment: Следует привести пример кода, когда происходит оишбка при компиляции. А так просто используйте `decltype(auto)` или просто `auto` в зависимости от стандарта для таких простых случаев.

Comment: @Harry первый вариант? у меня `gcc` не хочет с ошибкой `return type of out-of-line definition of 'B::bar' differs from that in the declaration`

Comment: @MrBin так это и есть пример кода, сейчас добавлю метку `gcc` тогда

Comment: Ну да, первый вариант компилируется без ошибок и предупреждений.

Comment: @Harry проверьте на `gcc`, если у вас есть, пожалуйста

Comment: Уже :) Достаточно зайти на http://ideone.com/ и там покомпилировать. Не работает. Но кто из них поступает строго по стандарту - увы, не скажу...

Comment: проверил `clang`, там тоже ошибка, так что метку удалю

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Компилятор не может понять, что эти типы одинаковые, потому что из `T B<T>::bar()` это совершенно не очевидно. Просто какой-то `T`. Чтобы избежать писанины либо просто используйте `auto` в объявлении и определении, либо, если автовыведение по какой-то причине не подходит, используйте хвостовую запись возвращаемого значения:

```
template<typename T>
auto B<T>::bar() -> BRet {
    return 42;
}
```

Почему же тогда нет проблем с этим кодом `T A<T>::foo()`? С ним нет проблем, потому что компилятор видит, что `ARet` и `T` в классе `A` жёстко связаны через `using`. А вот с `B` не всё так просто. В `B` `BRet` является зависимым типом, и зависит от он шаблона `A<T>`. Казалось бы, загляни в `A<T>` и посмотри, что `ARet` это тоже самое, что и `T`, но это сделать **невозможно**. Невозможно по одной простой причине: специализации.

Допустим, мы имеем вот такую специализацию класса `A`:

```
template<>
struct A<int> {
    using ARet = void;
    //...
};
```

И всё. `T` и `ARet` для `A<int>` (а значит и для `BRet`) больше не тождественны!

Разбор шаблонов является процессом, проходящим в 2 этапа (неформально именуется это всё two-phase name lookup). На первом этапе определяются все независимые от шаблонных параметров имена, а вот на втором (во время инстанциации) определяются все зависимые. Зависимые имена до инстанциации не определяются!

Очевидно, что объявление и определение функции должны быть проанализированы на первом этапе, т.к. код шаблонов должен быть правильным C++-кодом, вне зависимости от того, с чем он будет инстанциирован. Но мы имеем ситуацию, в которой у нас есть объявление функции с зависимым типом и её определение с типом независимым. До этапа инстанциирования компилятор не в состоянии понять, что эти типы одинаковые или разные, но ему нужно знать это на первом этапе. Отсюда и ошибка.

Почему нет ошибки в MSVC? Потому что компилятор от Microsoft исторически не имел реализации двухфазного поиска, а разбирал шаблоны как токены. В результате, MSVC «съедал» много некорректного шаблонного кода и не давился. Сейчас ситуация изменилась и в MSVC появился двухфазный поиск, но, как мы можем видеть, до ума он ещё не доведён. Немного подробнее можно почитать тут: [Two-phase name lookup support comes to MSVC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/09/11/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/)

Comment: а почему для `foo` он может понять, а для `bar` нет? в чём разница?

Comment: @Игорь, скорее всего потому, что имя зависимое, а зависимые имена могут быть проверены только при инстанциации. Конкретные цитаты из стандарта приведу позже, пока не могу.

Comment: ок, тогда ещё добавьте потом, пожалуйста, почему `VS` (судя по `ideone`) это компилирует без ошибок

Comment: @Игорь, обновил ответ. Я не стал выискивать все релевантные цитаты, просто привел контрпример и объяснил своими словами. Думаю, что контрпримера достаточно, чтобы не искать строго обоснования через цитаты.

Comment: супер, спасибо, всё понятно